# Large number of rows in Kusto

Tags: azure, sandbox, azure-data-explorer, kql

Scenario:
I have a graph edge list stored as Kusto Table. I need to divide them into groups(connected components)
I am running Kusto Python Plugins to run DFS and assign a group number to each edge in the same table(extending another column)
Sometimes there can be a large number of rows, millions of rows. Once the groups has been formed, we can return the table to the c# API in a paginated manner, but how to run the python script in such large number of rows?
Sometimes it takes 2 or more minutes to run. Can I decrease this time, given that we know that these scripts run in the sandbox in kusto cluster?
Please suggest some startergy.

Problem Statement: Given a table containing list of people who gave and borrowed money. Now we have to form groups of people which are connected to each other. Eg if A gives money to B and C. C gives money to D . Then A,B,C,D are connected

Pseudo Code:

````
Payment // table Payment has columns- LenderName,LenderPhone,BorrowerName,BorrowerPhone
|evaluate python(
typeof(*,GroupNo:int),
```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,name,phone):
        self.name=name
        self.phone=phone
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.name==other.name and self.phone==other.phone
    def __ne__(self,other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name,self.phone))
    
def get_adjacency_list(connections):
    # Personis a dataframe with columns- LenderName,LenderPhone,BorrowerName,BorrowerPhone
    
    
    
    adjacency_list=dict()#dictionary of Node-->Set<Nodes>
    for index, row in connections.iterrows():
        node1=Node(row["LenderName"],row["LenderPhone"])
        node2=Node(row["BorrowerName"],row["BorrowerPhone"])
        
        if(node1 not in adjacency_list):
            adjacency_list[node1]=set()
        if(node2 not in adjacency_list):
            adjacency_list[node2]=set()
        
        adjacency_list[node1].add(node2)
        adjacency_list[node2].add(node1)
    return adjacency_list
    



def run_dfs(node,group_no,visited,graph_list,groups):
    visited.add(node)
    groups[node]=group_no
    for next_node in graph_list[node]:
        if next_node not in visited:
            visited.add(next_node)
            run_dfs(next_node,group_no,visited,graph_list,groups)

            
def get_groups(graph_list):
    groups=dict()
    visited=set()
    group_no=0
    for node in graph_list.keys():
        print(node)
        if node not in visited:
            group_no+=1
            run_dfs(node,group_no,visited,graph_list,groups)
    return groups

graph_list=get_adjacency_list(df)
groups=get_groups(graph_list)

result=df;

result["GroupNo"]=df.apply(lambda row: groups.get(Node(row["LenderName"],row["LenderPhone"]),-1),axis=1)
```
)
````

Comment: **(1)** Have you read about sandboxes? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/sandboxes#runtime **(2)** Have you set a benchmark? For how long does your script run, on your own computer, after you already loaded the data to memory?

Comment: When I run the query on kusto explorer, it takes 2 minutes to run on approx 200,000 records. My query includes a python plugin. Can this be improved?

Comment: You are asking if a code that I have never seen, could be improved? Please follow the instructions on my 1st comment.

Comment: I have added the code for your reference. this code takes time to execute when the number of rows becomes high .
main question is- Can we make our query run faster, so that the sandbox does not get throttled on high number of request from the API server

Comment: Is there a reason you are ignoring my request to follow through my 1st comment?

Comment: What exactly do you want me to focus on from the documentation that answers my query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246052/discussion-between-jaime-and-david--markovitz).

Comment: (1) The link I gave you points directly to "Runtime", so "Runtime" it is. (2) Do the benchmark and provide the results and then we could understand if we need to focus on the sandbox or the code

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat-https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246052/discussion-between-jaime-and-david--markovitz

Comment: Can you please join the chat link and reply?